# looking for name for this flower

Tags: identification, perennials

[image: I t]

Can somebody tell me the name of this flower? Thanks

Comment: welcome to gardening.se It may be that someone will know the name immediately but it's preferable if you post your general location (country/state) to help with identification.

Comment: And foliage is important for correct ID - do you have a photo showing more of the plant in terms of size, growth habit and leaves?

Comment: I think I know precisely which Geranium it is - but do need to see the leaves for confirmation

Comment: Thank you for the feed back, that helped. Since I was doing macro photography at the time, all the leaves are blurred out on all the photos I took. But your answers gave me enough to go on. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Graham Chiu and Bamboo are right that the location and leaves will help people recognize it. But for now, I think it looks like some kind of geranium. Possibly even Geranium caespitosum as seen in this picture from Wikipedia:

[image: G. caespitosum from Wikipedia]

Yours looks a little more purple though, ... so I dunno. Send some pictures of the leaves & the whole plant though if you can, and the experts here will surely nail it.

Comment: Thank you. That helps. The lighting will cause some color change. I think the leaves were like those in your photo. All mine are blurred out. But your photos provides me with the info I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: Definitely Geranium,  but not this one - it doesn't have the long filaments extending from the buds...

Comment: Are those filaments from buds or just spent flowers? If filaments-on-buds, then I have to retract my answer - I've worked with and sold over three dozen varieties the past few years and I've never seen one with filaments like that on buds. G. maculatum has something similar on spent flowers, but not on buds. Very interesting.

Comment: @ Jurp, yeah, I think those are spent flowers that you see in the picture from Hilde Stapgens. If you look close you can see the green beginnings of the characteristic Geranium "crane's bill" type seed-pod poking out of the sepals as well.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so no photos of the leaves are available, in which case, check out Geranium macrorrhizum - might be 'Bevan's variety', 'Ingerwersens variety' or 'Czakor', depends how accurate the colour of the flowers is in your photo, but the flowers have these long stamens with orange anthers, and the flower buds have the very fine, long filaments showing at the top, unlike many Geranium varieties. Image of G. macrorrhizum 'Bevan's Variety' here https://www.classicroses.co.uk/geranium-macrorrhizum-bevans-variety.html

Answer (score 1):

[Johnson's Geranium Blue](https://www.highcountrygardens.com/perennial-plants/unique-plants/geranium-johnsons-blue)

I have had lots of my own masses of this plant and this is my knee jerk reaction to your picture.  We have far better IDers on this site so this is but a start.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like Geranium x cantabrigiense (the original variety, not Biokovo). This is an easy one to confirm - rub the leaves and smell them. If they smell citrusy and the plant is low-growing, then this ID is correct.

Comment: Here's a link to a photo.: https://www.google.com/search?q=geranium+cantabrigiense&client=firefox-b-1-ab&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=lMSfS_tps5RCcM%253A%252CzOZeFVvdPKz0gM%252C_&usg=__tndnLWdz_F8tkHD9KQIe2y7ICHA%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwgNu-nfzZAhVFyGMKHTyYA8gQ9QEIQDAC#imgrc=DIYWkr2PTo7oFM: